# Remove the middle of each word

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I would like to remove the middle (non-first and last character) of each word in a string.

```
"Bob" #=> "Bb"
"12309123" #=> "13"
"Davy Jones" #=> "Dy Js"
```

How can I go about doing that?

Comment: What's the expected output for `"A"` or `"Be"`?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, post the code you've tried and what specifically is giving you trouble.

Comment: @Iggy Just in case you want to achieve this without the use of regular expressions, my answer shows you how you can do it.

Comment: Define a word. Things that are not whitespace? Only text and digits? What if there's a hyphenated/compound word.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `(?<=\S)\S+(?=\S)` with nothing

`(?<=\S)` is a lookbehind that checks there is a non-space character before.

`(?=\S)` is a lookahead that checks there is a non-space character after.

Note: I don't know exactly what you call "a word", perhaps the character class `\w` is better fitted for your needs. In this case you can avoid lookarounds and write your pattern with non word-boundaries like this:

```
\B\w+\B
```

Comment: There is a small, easily fixable problem: `"How now, brown cow?".gsub(/(?<=\S)\S+(?=\S)/, "") #=> "Hw n, bn c?"`, but should return `"Hw nw, bn cw?"`, as the OP only wants to remove the middle characters of "each word", and the comma and question mark are not parts of words.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: as you can see I gave an other pattern in the note for this case (if "word" in the question means "word characters").

Comment: Ah, `\B\w+\B` is very cool!

Answer (score 2):

Just use [String's `[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) slice:

```
foo = 'barbaz'
foo[1..-2] = ''
foo # => "bz"
```

Comment: Question includes, "..each word in a string".

Comment: Define "word". The OP hadn't defined that and until it had been continuing with code wasn't going to be that useful.

Answer (score 1):

this isn't as clever perhaps, but it does the same thing: `"my dog has fleas".gsub(/(\w)\w+(\w)/, "\\1\\2") #=>my dg hs fs`

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/q11iit) /
[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU5vQ2/2)

Comment: In Ruby, you'd need to write `s = "my dog has fleas"; s.gsub(/(\w)\w+(\w)/, '\1\2') #=> "my dg hs fs"` or  `s.gsub(/(\w)\w+(\w)/) { $1+$2 } #=> "my dg hs fs". I don't think Ruby supports the `g` option.

Comment: seems to work: $stdout.write("my dog has fleas".gsub(/(\w)\w+(\w)/, "\\1\\2"))   http://ideone.com/q11iit

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Ruby doesn't support the `g` flag. That's what `gsub` is for.

Comment: We don't use `$stdout.write` in Ruby. The default channel is STDOUT and `puts` is the defacto method for outputting on STDOUT. `write` is supported but it isn't as smart as `puts`.

Comment: noted.  (never programmed with Ruby you can probably tell ;))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this without the use of regular expressions:

```
original = 'Davy Jones'.split( )

original.each do |string|
    words = string.split(//)
    no_middle = "#{words[0]}#{words[words.length- 1]}"
    print no_middle
    print ' '
end
```

Output:

```
Dy Js
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "How now, brown cow, are you a Jersey?"

str.gsub(/\w+/) { |s| (s.size==1) ? s : s[0]+s[-1] }
  #=> "Hw nw, bn cw, ae yu a Jy?"
```

...but @CasimiretHippolyte's

```
str.gsub(/\B\w+\B/, "")
  #=> "Hw nw, bn cw, ae yu a Jy?"
```

is the cat's meow.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the standard Ruby `String#gsub` method.  Here's how it looks:

```
string.gsub(/(\w)\w+(\w)/, "\\1\\2")
```

This matches only when there are 3 or more characters by using `\w+` as the internal matcher pattern.  As a better solution than using `\w*` in the same place, there's no loss of performance by incidentally matching 2 character words and replacing that word with itself.

Alternatively, you can supply a block to `#gsub` that gets called on each match:

```
string.gsub(/\b\w\w\w+\b/) {|s| s[0]+s[-1] }
```

The block version makes certain that at least 3 characters match, in order improve performance by not invoking the block and string concatenation unless it's called for.  There are other (perhaps better) regex expressions that could be used here, but this one suits the purpose just fine.

`#gsub` also has a modify-in-place version that you can use, called `#gsub!`.  It works the same way, but will change the string that you pass to it.  I give examples with `#gsub`, but you can use the same techniques with `#gsub!` if that what you prefer to use.

And here's an example using your sample strings and one other, using both methods:

```
strings = [ \
  "Bob",         #=> "Bb"
  "12309123",    #=> "13"
  "Davy Jones",  #=> "Dy Js"
  "How now brown cow, may your day be a model of happiness"
]

strings.each do |string|
  puts "String '#{string}' becomes '#{string.gsub(/(\w)\w+(\w)/, "\\1\\2")}'"
  puts "String '#{string}' becomes '#{string.gsub(/\b\w\w\w+\b/) {|s| s[0]+s[-1] }}'"
end
```

This will output the following:

```
String 'Bob' becomes 'Bb'
String 'Bob' becomes 'Bb'
String '12309123' becomes '13'
String '12309123' becomes '13'
String 'Davy Jones' becomes 'Dy Js'
String 'Davy Jones' becomes 'Dy Js'
String 'How now brown cow, may your day be a model of happiness' becomes 'Hw nw bn cw, my yr dy be a ml of hs'
String 'How now brown cow, may your day be a model of happiness' becomes 'Hw nw bn cw, my yr dy be a ml of hs'
```